# Can't find object.(Object undefined when it is defined)

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am learning Angular and I do not understand why I can't get an object's property from component.ts file in template.

My code:

from app.component.html

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Select an option</mat-label>
  <mat-select
  (click)="methood()" >
    <mat-option
    *ngFor="let color of colors"
    [value]="color.id">
      {{color.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

from app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  colors: [
    { id: 1, name: 'Red' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Green' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Blue' }
  ];

  methood() {console.log(this.colors, 'hello'); }
}
```

It should show a dropdown list with colors but it doesn't.

Comment: what does it say in the console?

Comment: it says 'undefined "hello" '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please checkout the basics of typescript and how to assign values.

You tried to assign by this statement:

```
colors: [
    { id: 1, name: 'Red' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Green' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Blue' }
  ];
```

while it has to be:

```
colors = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Red' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Green' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Blue' }
  ];
```

or

```
colors: any[] = [ <--- or your type
    { id: 1, name: 'Red' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Green' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Blue' }
  ];
```

Answer (score 2):

You used a `:` instead of an `=`

```
export class AppComponent {
  colors = [ // <-- here
    { id: 1, name: 'Red' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Green' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Blue' }
  ];

  methood() {console.log(this.colors, 'hello'); }
}
```

Comment: u came too fast :DF